# create local server on android

Tags: php, android

I want a develop a web application with php, and I want a run my apps with a android device. But my device will not be connected to internet, so I must create a local server on the device to run my php code. Is it possible? And if it's possible how?

Comment: I doubt if such a feature exists to support PHP server on a mobile device.

Comment: Useful link, but looks like the development of the server is in early stage.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this](http://research.nokia.com/page/231) page, developing Web Server for mobile devices is still on the research phase. Most probably you would need to use some kind of simulator for Android and develop your App on powerful desktop PC.

**EDIT:** Looks like such a [server](http://phpforandroid.net) exists for Android.

Answer (score 1):

Please use KSWEB.apk. This app supports PHP, SQL, html, csc, but it requires 3 android devices. The first serves as router, the 2nd device is a local server and the 3rd devices is a monitor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your need to have a web server running on your phone, but if you have a wireless router and your phone can connect to it, can you not install an Apache server with PHP support on your development PC and access it via your phone's wireless connection?